# .htaccess : Can't rewrite assets with a special host name to a proper path

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I have a `Laravel` app which I want it to load an angular app when the user has been authenticated and requested a special subdomain which resides in `/public` directory.

Assuming my `public` contains :

```
\---ng
    \---app
       +---bower_components
       |   +---angular
       |   +---angular-loader
       |   +---angular-mocks
       |   +---angular-route
       |   \---html5-boilerplate
       |       +---dist
       |       |   +---css
       |       |   +---doc
       |       |   +---img
       |       |   \---js
       |       |       \---vendor
       |       +---src
       |       |   +---css
       |       |   +---doc
       |       |   +---img
       |       |   \---js
       |       |       \---vendor
       |       \---test
       +---components
       |   \---version
       +---view1
       \---view2
```

my `.htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.domain\.com
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) ng/app/$1 [L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Problem :**

When I request e.g. `http://sub.domain.com:8080/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css`

Laravel returns **404**.

How can I load this ng app from public directory, but also run the request through laravel's `index.php` to check for Authentication and Authorization

Answer (score 1):

`/bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css` doesn't map to an existing file. This is the reason, why the condition of the second rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

doesn't match and the third rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

is applied. Laravel doesn't know how to serve this request and reports an error 404.

See [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for details

> **REQUEST_FILENAME**
>   The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used in virtual host context, the same value as REQUEST_URI. Depending on the value of AcceptPathInfo, the server may have only used some leading components of the REQUEST_URI to map the request to a file.

---

If you want to check the request path against a file, you can prefix the variable with `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ng/app` and see, if it corresponds to an existing file, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ng/app%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ ng/app%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Instead of:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```